# How can I sort img elements according to an attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a list of img elements in a div, like this :

```
<img src="..." pct="38"/>
```

The value of pct is different for every image. I've managed to create a list containing all my images, with an `each()` loop.

```
var tab[];
```

But I have no idea of how to sort it easily, and if there is a quick way. What should I do ?

Comment: What do you mean by "list", an `<ul>`? What do you mean by "table"? Do you want to tell us that the `tab` variable holds an array?

Comment: Yes that's it, tab is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function and pass it a dedicated comparison function :

```
var strcmp = function(str1, str2) {
    return ( ( str1 == str2 ) ? 0 : ( ( str1 > str2 ) ? 1 : -1 ) );
};
// to sort by src :
tab.sort(function(a,b) {
    return strcmp(a.attr('src'), b.attr('src'));
});
// to sort by "pct" :
tab.sort(function(a,b) {
    return strcmp(a.attr('pct'), b.attr('pct'));
});
// to sort by "pct" as numbers :
tab.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.attr('pct') - b.attr('pct');
});
```

This assumes your `tab` array contains jQuery objects. If that's not the case, use `$(a).attr('pct')` instead of `a.attr('pct')`.

Comment: he seems to want `$(a).attr("pct") - $(b).attr("pct")`…

Answer (score 2):

If you define a `sortByPct` function like this where `a` and `b` are DOM elements:

```
var sortByPct = function(a, b) {
  var aNum = new Number($(a).attr("pct"));
  var bNum = new Number($(b).attr("pct"));
  return aNum == bNum ? 0 : (aNum < bNum ? -1 : 1);
}
```

... you will be able to sort your array the following way:

```
tab.sort(sortByPct);
```